# Problem with cutting the model using a rectangular mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I used this tutorial: https://youtu.be/moPDPB4MY2U?si=fjNLYkZXMqlG3JUD to separate a 3D model into two parts. I did everything as in the tutorial, but when I got to using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, something didn't work as in the video.

[image]

I used a rectangular mesh to cut the model as in the video, but when I select the rectangular mesh and my model and then use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, the rectangular mesh removes, but only one half of the two parts of the model I want to cut remains.

The other disappears and is nowhere to be found. To do the next step in the tutorial, I need to cut the model according to the line traced by the rectangular mesh, so that I can then spread the two parts and make the pins.

What have I done wrong? How do I solve this problem? (In the photos you can see how I set up the rectangular mesh and what remains after using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: I can barely see it in the screenshot because it's not close enough. But your rectangular mesh looks like a simple flat mesh. Did you give it a _Solidify_ modifier like he does in the video?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I think I did, but I'm not sure, so I applied it again and now when I try to use ctrl + minus again, the whole model disappears and some orange dots/dashes remain

Comment: It is also not visible in the screenshot if your mesh is somehow messy, overlapping/duplicate geometry, non-manifold edges etc., all these things can make problems with the _Boolean_ operation. Some of these issues can be overcome by using different settings in the _Boolean_ modifier, but `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Numpad -` is the shortcut for the _Bool Tool_ operation which automatically applies the modifier, so you cannot change settings afterwards... but when your mesh has issues and even when you get the modifier to ignore them, they might still make problems in 3D printing...

Comment: How can I check if my rectangular mesh is "somehow messy"? Or what should I do if I think that it is overlapping etc.?